# jQuery responsive calls

Tags: jquery, responsive-design

I have a responsive web layout that calls two different navigations. I am trying to call one navigation in when the screen size is bigger than 768px wide and the other when the screen width is small than 768px wide. The problem is this script works except if I start out on a small screen then go to a large screen I have to hit refresh to get it to work and vice versa.

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if ( $(window).width() > 768) {
// initiate page scroller plugin
    $('body').pageScroller({
        navigation: '.pageScrollerNav',
        scrollOffset: -40,

    });
 }
 else {
 // initiate page scroller plugin
    $('body').pageScroller({
        navigation: '.pageScrollerNav2',
        scrollOffset: -40,

    });
 }


});
```

Comment: Attach your call to `window.onresize` and it should listen for when screen size changes.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/resize/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read comments:

```
function rezisingScroll() { //make it a function so you can call it n times
    if ($(window).width() > 768) {
        // initiate page scroller plugin
        $('body').pageScroller({
            navigation: '.pageScrollerNav',
            scrollOffset: -40,

        });
    } else {
        // initiate page scroller plugin
        $('body').pageScroller({
            navigation: '.pageScrollerNav2',
            scrollOffset: -40,

        });
    }
}


$(document).ready(function() {

    rezisingScroll(); //call once when document is ready

    $(window).resize(function() { // attach to resize event
        rezisingScroll(); //call everytime window resizes
    });
});
```

You can't simply add to resize directly because it isn't  fired when page loads or when DOM is ready. That's why I made it a function, so you can call once when dom is ready and N times when resize occurs.

Comment: it seems your method would work but for some reason it is doing the same thing. It may be something with my plugin. http://www.jonasandnicole.com

Comment: @jacks3 Probably is something related to pagescroller not allowing two instances or something. Will look into the docs see if I find something to kill it before adding the new.

Comment: @jacks3 I tried your webpage, when window is resized, shows an iOS-like menu and when window is bigger, shows a side menu (and the top one with contacts). What you were expecting other than that?

Comment: Notice how the navigation works when it is large screen (side navigation) but when you minimize and try to use the iOS like navigation it doesn't work unless you refresh the page that size..

Comment: @jacks3 Seems documentation does not specify how destroy the plugin. Will try check how it hooks on the element to destroy it before calling again.

Answer (score 1):

you could bind to the window onOrientationChange event if you are on a mobile device, and or bind to the window resize event

```
$(window).bind("resize orientationchange", function(){
    if ( $(window).width() > 768) {

    $('body').pageScroller({
        navigation: '.pageScrollerNav',
        scrollOffset: -40,

    });
    }else {

       $('body').pageScroller({
          navigation: '.pageScrollerNav2',
          scrollOffset: -40,

        });
    }
})
```